# iisnode not working on windows 10 home edition

Tags: node.js, iis, windows-10, iisnode

I downloaded the latest iisnode from https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/releases ([0.2.26 full](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/releases/download/v0.2.26/iisnode-full-v0.2.26-x64.msi))

I downloaded url rewrite module 2.1 from https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi

Installed both

Then I ran `%programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat` with adminitrative rights

Restarted my machine (just in case)

I went to http://localhost/node/

I get the following error on every link:

```
Error Code     0x80070021

Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Config File    \\?\C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\helloworld\web.config


Config Source:

    6: 
    7:     <handlers>
    8:       <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
```

I guess it's not accepting iisnode as a valid handler

Any idea?

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Excelent, both methods worked like a charm, thanks a lot (sorry for the delay in answering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browse to "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" and open notepad as administrator and open applicationHost.config file.

Find the section that showed up in the “config source” part of the error message page (typically “modules” or “handlers”).

Change the overrideModeDefault attribute to be “Allow”.  The whole line now looks like:

```
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />"
```

OR

You could also try below setting:

- open iis manager, select node.

[image]

- from select section dropdown select "system.webserver/handlers" from action pane select unlock.

[image]

after doing changes restart the iis.